# Adicionando Partial Views à minha página principal através de uma modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, modal

Possuo uma página com um botão que chama uma modal e nessa modal há uma tabela com os produtos, que quando clico em um registro dos produtos ele é adicionado na minha página. Está adicionando somente o primeiro produto, mais de um não é adicionado.

tenho isso em meu `controller`, uma função para chamar a `Partial`.

```
public ActionResult NovaLinhaProduto()
        {
            Produto produto = _produtoRepository.GetById(int.Parse(Request["id"]));

            var ordemCompraProduto = new OrdemCompraProdutoViewModel();
            ViewBag.produto = produto;

            return PartialView("_LinhaProduto", ordemCompraProduto);
        }
```

e tenho isso e meu **modal**, que da um `append` em minha página.

```
$.get('/OrdemCompra/NovaLinhaProduto?id=' + id, function (template) {
                    parent.$("#Produtos_Adicionados").append(template);
                });
```

*View*:

```
 <div id="Produtos_Adicionados" name="Produtos_Adicionados" class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/lupa.gif")" id="PopUp_produtos" style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-white">
     </div>
     @if (Model != null)
     {
         if (Model.OrdemCompraProdutoss != null)
         {
             foreach (var ordemProdutos in Model.OrdemCompraProdutoss)
             {
                 @Html.Partial("_LinhaProduto", ordemProdutos);
             }
         }
     }
 </div>
```

Comment: Não te está a dar nenhum erro de javascript? Muito estranho não estar a funcionar..

Comment: Não está CesarMiguel.

Comment: Você pode colocar o trecho da *View* onde essa *Partial* deve ser adicionada?

Comment: Coloquei um breakpoint na função que chama a partial, na segunda adição o break vai direto para Global.asax.cs e fica carregando a página.

Comment: Não sei cara acho que deve ta demorando pra carregar. Muito estranho. Tem hora que a página só fica carregando e demora.

Comment: Ele adicionou, mas eu entrei no breakpoint e fiquei andando bem devagar com ele ai funcionou, alguém tem alguma solução? Deve ser questão de tempo.

Comment: Faltou o código da *Partial* em si. A princípio está tudo certo.

Comment: Cigano ele adicionou mas foi da forma que te falei, não está demorando muito a renderização da partial?